# Can Unity and GNOME Shell apps run on LXDE?

Tags: lxde

I am currently using GNOME Shell, Unity and GNOME Classic on Ubuntu 11.10. I would like to know if I download LXDE, would the GTK applications that I have on GNOME 3.2 (which is being used by Unity and GNOME Shell) be able to be used in LXDE, or do I have to install separate software that can only be used by LXDE?

Because the apps I install on Unity Shell can also be accessed and used on GNOME Shell (I suppose this is because they are both running on GNOME 3.2 which uses GTK+3 libraries) can I find the same apps I install on GNOME Shell and Unity on LXDE?

Here's what I mean: I install GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 11.10. I am able to access the apps I installed on Unity on GNOME Shell from the search bar. Even the bookmarks I save on Firefox in Unity will also be saved in Firefox in GNOME Shell. What I am asking is will it be the same situation where I do not have to install apps specifically for LXDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special reason why *gnome-shell* or *unity* applications should not run under LXDE or any other desktop environments.

The only exceptions are applications that make specific use of capabilities and functionality that is very specific to a particular desktop environment.

LXDE/Lubuntu applications you will find are often GTK+ based - thus the vast majority of GTK+ apps you see in blogs running in Unity/Gnome-shell should work for LXDE.

If you are a purist, you should look out for the dependencies that a particular application brings with it.  Some applications will have a dependency that would involve installing the majority of one desktop environment/stack.

To test what dependencies an application requires try a simulated install i.e.

```
sudo apt-get -s install [package-name]
```

Look at the sections:
`The following extra packages will be installed:`

and

`The following NEW packages will be installed`

If the list is particularly lengthy then perhaps you should consider an alternative - less bulky/dependent application.

Occasionally after installing an application, it does not appear in the menu.  For these applications have a look at the applications *.desktop* file in `/usr/share/applications`.  Some applications desktop file has an entry similar to `OnlyShowIn=Unity`.  I would remove this entry and it should (after logging out/logging in) appear in the menu again.